# Custom Controller: How to return a 404

Tags: 9

I have a custom controller with a parametric route:

```yml
site_checkout.greeting.show:
  path: '/path/{a_id}/{b_id}/greeting'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\GreetingController::greetingShow'
```

How can I display the normal 404 page, if a_id or b_id are not found in the database?

```php
class GreetingController extends ControllerBase {

  public function greetingShow($a_id, $b_id) {


    $a = AUtils::getAById($a_id);

    if(!$a || $b_id !== $a->get('uid')->getString() || $a->get('x')->getString() !== '1') {
      // just show the standard 404, but how?
    }

    return [];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just throw an exception anywhere in your controller and this is caught by Drupal to build a themed error page:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

...

  if (!$a || $b_id !== $a->get('uid')->getString() || $a->get('x')->getString() !== '1') {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
  }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thx a lot!